# not able to click on slds input icon

Tags: lightning-web-components, html

Below is the HTML

```
  <div class="slds-form-element">
        <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="combobox-id-3">Relate To</label>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <div class="slds-combobox_container">
                <div class="slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click slds-is-open"
                    aria-expanded="true" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox">
                    <div class="slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right" role="none">
                        <input type="text" class="slds-input slds-combobox__input slds-has-focus" data-id="combo-input"
                            aria-controls="listbox-id-4" autocomplete="off" role="textbox"
                            placeholder="Select an Option…" value={inputValue} onkeyup={handleInputChange} />
                        <span
                            class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-close slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right"
                            style="cursor: pointer; z-index:200; position:absolute" onclick={handleRemoveValue}>
                            <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close" size="x-small" alternative-text="Click here"
                                class="slds-icon slds-icon--selected slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-var-m-right_x-small">
                            </lightning-icon>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Which renders as below

[image]

below is JS

```
handleRemoveValue() {
    console.log('I am clicked');
}
```

Now expected behavior is when I click on the cross icon, it should log, `I am clicked` but the same is not happening, could someone please help what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a button tag instead of span. Below code should work for you

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
   <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="combobox-id-3">Relate To</label>
   <div class="slds-form-element__control">
      <div class="slds-combobox_container">
         <div class="slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click slds-is-open"
            aria-expanded="true" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox">
            <div class="slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right" role="none">
               <input type="text" class="slds-input slds-combobox__input slds-has-focus" data-id="combo-input"
                  aria-controls="listbox-id-4" autocomplete="off" role="textbox"
                  placeholder="Select an Option…" value={inputValue} onkeyup={handleInputChange} />
               <button class="sicon_container slds-button slds-button_icon 
                  slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right" 
                  title="Remove selected option"
                  onclick={handleRemoveValue}>
                  <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close" size="small">
                  </lightning-icon>
                  <span class="slds-assistive-text">Remove selected option</span>
               </button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked, would you please help me understand why it was not working with the span?

Comment: TBH, I am not sure why this isn't working. In the documentation [here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/input/#Icon-and-clear-button) a button is used, so recommended to use button. But I digged into your code, and found the icon becomes unclickable when we add `slds-input-has-icon` class to the `div` . Still not sure completely, about the reason.

Comment: Okay no problem, thank you for your help!